# Feasibility of 30MW DC transmission over 400m?

Tags: dc, high-voltage, power-engineering

We have an electric motor final load of 10-30MW, in an isolated industrial location.

The power source could be (Li-ion) battery packs, where each pack outputs 1500VDC, ~500A. Having 10-30 of these packs we get 10-30MW DC.

Can we efficiently transmit this over 200m-400m (yes! meters!) with standard cables?
Hitting <5% losses would be great.

Do we need a step-up converter? We want to stick to commodity equipment and voltages.

Comment: How much current do you need to transfer over that distance?  What kind of voltage drop can you tolerate?

Comment: @EugeneSh. This might replace a large diesel unit. I have no idea if it is feasible.

Comment: @YAZR Is the diesel unit used for generating electricity? Is there a good reason to replace it? How long would the batteries have to supply power for - would you need a diesel generator when they run out?

Comment: What do you consider "commodity equipment?" A 30 MW DC motor is something that would be built to order and available from few if any manufacturers. Do you actually have such a motor? What is the real story here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 10-30 packs won't get you 10-30 MW if each pack is 750 kW. You would need 40 of them to get 30 MW.

Also, you haven't said what you mean by 'standard cables', that could mean zip cord for all we know.

In parallel you would have 1500 V @ 20,000 A
In series you would have 60,000 V @ 500 A

You would need some seriously large cable to handle 20,000 A. With 1 in. thick cable you're talking several hundred volts per leg voltage drop.

At 60,000 V the losses would be a lot less, but you'd have some serious safety issues to deal with (not that 1500 V isn't dangerous as well).

You could do something in the middle with a series/parallel arrangement.

With parallel you're also going to have to think about how to combine them, it's less trouble putting batteries in series than in parallel.
And of course you're going to have to figure out how to charge them.

Honestly, I would recommend that you pay some engineers to do this for you rather than asking on the internet.

Comment: I am currently just checking the economics of replacing an ugly diesel unit with an electric setup. 

I am (obviously?) not an EE, and i not gonna be assembling such a monster myself.

We will charge using separate PVs to each pack, so thats a lot simpler and better documented.

Is it really recommended to hook these packs in series? We will probably max out at 15KV, and thats sounds like a decent rough  starting point.

Comment: @YAZR Could you give us a little more information to go on? Are you replacing a diesel motor with an electric one, or do you have an existing electric motor that is powered by a diesel generator? If it's a generator what is it's output voltage and current? What are the ratings of the electric motor?

Comment: I am hating the thought of doing the design of the switching and overload protection on a 15kV 2kA supply, there is a reason fuses and switches become 'problematic' in high power DC doings, and unlike in the case of something like a DC link between grids you cannot just do the protection in the AC domain. I am not seeing anything commodity about this.

Comment: @YAZR I'm not recommending one connection type or another, I'm just letting you know what you're dealing with. That much power is nothing to play around with whichever way it's connected. This is a job for someone who really knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Not a firm answer, but something you ought to consider.

Look at Battery Energy Storage Systems (BESS), that power companies are starting to deploy to help with peak load conditions and outages.  These are big packs of LiO batteries arranged to provide the voltage and current needed during such conditions.  They can be as big (a city block or parking lot) or as small (a refrigerator) as needed, depending on your energy storage needs.

But with this approach, you still need a way to charge the BESS.

Comment: Aren't they meant to be grid-tied for both charging and discharging? Can they be used stand-alone?

Comment: I don't know all the details.  But yes, they are tied into the grid for charging and discharging.  OP said battery packs, so I assume he has some way of charging them.  In my mind, they are the closest thing to an off-the-shelf (sort of) solution with the kind energy storage he's looking for.